# Adding different controls having same names in C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

I am working in C# windows forms application in which I am adding 3 different controls having same name **(a button, a textBox & a Label)** to my form.

Why there is error in button4_Click?

**CODE:**

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        TextBox myControl = new TextBox();
        myControl.Name = "myControl";
        this.Controls.Add(myControl);
 }

 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        Button myControl = new Button();
        myControl.Name = "myControl";
        this.Controls.Add(myControl);
 }

 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        Label myControl = new Label();
        myControl.Name = "myControl";
        this.Controls.Add(myControl);
 }

 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      ((ComboBox)this.Controls["myControl"]).Text = "myCombo"; // works
      ((TextBox)this.Controls["myControl"]).Text = "myText";   // error
      ((Label)this.Controls["myControl"]).Text = "myLabel";    // error
 }
```

Comment: You should name your buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Controls[string] indexer returns the first control whose name matches the string.  It will be hit and miss with your code but you probably have a ComboBox already added to the form with that same name.  The next statements go kaboom because you cannot cast a ComboBox to a TextBox.

Of course, do try to do the sane thing, give these controls different names.

Comment: I want to know that these all are added to form with same name. How?

Comment: Erm, just iterate Controls and count the ones with that name?  What is the point of this?

Answer (score 0):

`this.Controls["myControl"]` returns the first control named `myControl`.

This is a TextBox, not a Label.

Instead of accessing them through the `Controls` collection, you should store your controls in fields in the form class (perhaps using `List<T>`s).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one idea that might help you:

```
 void SetControlText(Type controlType, string controlName, string text) {
      foreach (var ctl in this.Controls.OfType<Control>()) {
        if (ctl.GetType() == controlType && ctl.Name == controlName) {
          ctl.Text = text;

          break;
        }
      }
    }
```

Or with LINQ only:

```
var item = this.Controls.OfType<Control>().Where(j => j.GetType() == controlType && j.Name == controlName).FirstOrDefault();
      if (item != null)
        item.Text = text;
```

Simply call the above function like so:

```
SetControlText(typeof(Button), "myButton", "Text was set!");
```

This function will iterate through all of the controls on the form, and when it finds the control type you specify with the name you specify, it will update the controls .Text field.